# Listrak Invalid Credentials error using Python requests_oauthlib

Tags: python, rest, requests-oauthlib

Trying to get a valid response from the Listrak API using requests_oauthlib and all I ever get is Invalid Credentials. Have attempted to reset the keys but same issue. Code is as follows, <> sections replaced with actual keys in my code:

```
#Imports
import requests
import requests_oauthlib
from oauthlib.oauth2 import BackendApplicationClient

#Keys
id = <client_id>
secret = <client_secret>
#Token URL
token_url = 'https://auth.listrak.com/OAuth2/Token'

#Auth Request
client = BackendApplicationClient(client_id=id)
oauth = requests_oauthlib.OAuth2Session(client=client)
token = oauth.fetch_token(
    token_url=token_url, client_id=id, client_secret=secret)
```

Debugging log:

```
2019-12-09 13:31:27,014 - requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - 4396 - Encoding `client_id` "<client_id>" with `client_secret` as Basic auth credentials.
2019-12-09 13:31:27,014 - requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - 4396 - Requesting url https://auth.listrak.com/OAuth2/Token using method POST.
2019-12-09 13:31:27,014 - requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - 4396 - Supplying headers {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'} and data {'grant_type': 'client_credentials'}
2019-12-09 13:31:27,014 - requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - 4396 - Passing through key word arguments {'timeout': None, 'auth': <requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth object at 0x03EBC5F8>, 'verify': True, 'proxies': None}.
2019-12-09 13:31:27,014 - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - 4396 - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): auth.listrak.com:443
2019-12-09 13:31:27,217 - urllib3.connectionpool - DEBUG - 4396 - https://auth.listrak.com:443 "POST /OAuth2/Token HTTP/1.1" 400 31
2019-12-09 13:31:27,217 - requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - 4396 - Request to fetch token completed with status 400.
2019-12-09 13:31:27,217 - requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - 4396 - Request url was https://auth.listrak.com/OAuth2/Token
2019-12-09 13:31:27,217 - requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - 4396 - Request headers were {'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.22.0', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8', 'Content-Length': '29', 'Authorization': 'Basic emludWp1YnEzczdibHc4dmRrMDY6SGgwQWIyZkJZWWcvLzVZMTF1M1djWGpZWFpLWWpzVFNxTW83ckNteDBScw=='}
2019-12-09 13:31:27,217 - requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - 4396 - Request body was grant_type=client_credentials
2019-12-09 13:31:27,217 - requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - 4396 - Response headers were {'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Date': 'Mon, 09 Dec 2019 19:31:26 GMT', 'Expires': '-1', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'Content-Length': '31'} and content {"error":"Invalid Credentials"}.
2019-12-09 13:31:27,217 - requests_oauthlib.oauth2_session - DEBUG - 4396 - Invoking 0 token response hooks.
```

I notice in line four the "auth" argument looks like `'auth': <requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth object at 0x03EBC5F8>` which seems strange to me. Seems like that should have some values? Any advice at all greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work on an old server that was using an older version of the oauth library, but when I updated, Listrak stopped working just like it did for you, and I have a feeling it's what you're experiencing here.

I haven't completely sorted out what exactly is happening under the hood, but I got this to work when I passed `include_client_id=True` in `oauth.fetch_token()`. So it would be:

```
token = oauth.fetch_token(
    token_url=token_url, 
    client_id=id, 
    client_secret=secret,
    include_client_id=True)
```

(edited for clarity)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'm a little confused, are you saying that his `token = oauth.fetch_token(
    token_url=token_url, client_id=id, client_secret=secret)` should be replaced with `token = oauth.fetch_token(
    token_url=token_url, include_client_id=client_id, client_secret=secret)`?. If that's the case, why not write that all in your answer, to help the easily confused like me, and other future readers. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies for the lack of clarity, and thanks for the feedback! What I mean is it's an _additional_ parameter, like this: ```token = oauth.fetch_token(
    token_url=token_url, client_id=id, client_secret=secret, include_client_id=True)```. I also noticed I used `client_id` instead of True, which would have likely made more sense.